# sys.dm_database_encryption_keys returns 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

`select * from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` returning 0 rows in SQL server.

Anyone please help me with this.

Comment: It requires permissions. Are you connected with sa or an administrative account?

Comment: Yes connected with administrative account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-database-encryption-keys-transact-sql), the `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` view returns information about database encryption (if it is configured and you have the required permissions).

If you want to enable Transparent Data Encryption you need to follow the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption). More specifically, the `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` view will return data after you execute the `CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY` statement.

Transparent Data Encryption is available only in SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition, Enterprise Edition or Developer Edition, but in SQL Server 2017 and earlier versions it was available only in Enterprise Edition or Developer Edition (see [the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15) [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017)).